# Recalibration of constants with ordered logit for forecasting

Tags: forecasting, ordered-logit, choice-modeling

I have **estimated an order logit model**: I have one utility function (without constant, in the form $\sum_i \beta_i * x_i$) with cuts and I estimated the $\beta_i$ and the cuts on revealed preference data (sample of the population).

I would like now to **apply this model on two synthetic populations** that I have, one for today and one for the future. For each individual in the synthetic population, I compute the probability of each possible output (0, 1, 2, …, 6).

**Problem**: In the revealed preference data, the dependent variable is on average 0.6, while in the synthetic population (today version), the average of the output of the model is 0.3.

In **standard logit models**, it is recommended to **recalibrate the alternative speciﬁc constants against observed market shares** (see e.g. [Discrete Choice Methods with Simulation](https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2.html), by Kenneth Train, [chapter 2.8, page 33](https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2nd/Ch02_p9-33.pdf)). In my particular case, there is no constant, but I was thinking of **including a constant in the utility function in order to correct for the different nature of the data for estimation** (revealed preference data) **and simulation/forecasting** (synthetic population).

Does this approach make sense to you? Has anyone done such a process in the scientific literature? I have found nothing till now.

In any case, I need to make a correction in order to reproduce the aggregate observation of 0.6, before being able to use my model for forecasting. If you have any other strategy than including a constant, I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did not include a constant. Instead, I've calibrated the cuts (without changing the utility function) in order to reproduce the market shares using the synthetic population of today. Then, I applied the calibrated model on the synthetic population for the future.